# Firebase Cloud Messaging with serverside API push for obj-c

Tags: objective-c, firebase-cloud-messaging

currently I working to implement Firebase Push Notification in my apps.

I found this:

1. **[background]** Using **Firebase Console** my apps can get the notification from system tray with remote notification
2. **[foreground]** Using **Firebase Console** my apps can get the notification from log, but i can make it into notification center with local notification
3. **[foreground]** Using **Our Dashboard** which managed by PHP serverside, I can get notification from log, but i can make it into notification center with local notification

The problem is, how can i get the notification (log is fine) if my apps in background with **Our Dashboard** which managed by PHP serverside?

I found that there is different between json I got from Firebase Console and our managed serverside dashboard, is that a problem that my apps cant handle? and how i can handle it? can I get the sample of the code to solve this problem?

This is the different between json i got from **firebase console** and **our managed serverside dashboard**

[firebase console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sY7u2.png)
[our managed serverside dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rr8jA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is possible by using the normal FCM api.

Please review the differences between `Display-Message` and `Data-Message` here: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages

and see all the parameters in the reference page:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref